# Adding missing rows and setting column value to zero based on current dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandasql

```
dic= {'distinct_id': {0: 1,
  1: 2,
  2: 3,
  3: 4,
  4: 5},
 'first_name': {0: 'Joe',
  1: 'Barry',
  2: 'David',
  3: 'Marcus',
  4: 'Anthony'},
 'activity': {0: 'Jump',
  1: 'Jump',
  2: 'Run',
  3: 'Run',
  4: 'Climb'},
 'tasks_completed': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 1},
 'tasks_available': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 3}}

tasks = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

I'm trying to make every id/name pair have a row for every unique activity, for example I want "Joe" to have rows where the activity column is "Run" and "Climb", but I want him to have a 0 in the tasks_completed column (those rows not being present already means that he hasn't done these activity tasks). I have tried using df.iterrows() and making a list of the unique ids and activity names and checking to see if they're both present, but it didn't work. Any help is very appreciated!

This is what I am hoping to have:

```
  1: 2,
  2: 3,
  3: 4,
  4: 5,
  5: 1,
  6: 1,
  7: 2,
  8: 2,
  9: 3,
  10: 3,
  11: 4,
  12: 4,
  13: 5,
  14: 5},
 'email': {0: 'Joe',
  1: 'Barry',
  2: 'David',
  3: 'Marcus',
  4: 'Anthony',
  5: 'Joe',
  6: 'Joe',
  7: 'Barry',
  8: 'Barry',
  9: 'David',
  10: 'David',
  11: 'Marcus',
  12: 'Marcus',
  13: 'Anthony',
  14: 'Anthony'},
 'activity': {0: 'Jump',
  1: 'Jump',
  2: 'Run',
  3: 'Run',
  4: 'Climb',
  5: 'Run',
  6: 'Climb',
  7: 'Run',
  8: 'Climb',
  9: 'Jump',
  10: 'Climb',
  11: 'Climb',
  12: 'Jump',
  13: 'Run',
  14: 'Jump'},
 'tasks_completed': {0: 3,
  1: 3,
  2: 3,
  3: 3,
  4: 1,
  5: 0,
  6: 0,
  7: 0,
  8: 0,
  9: 0,
  10: 0,
  11: 0,
  12: 0,
  13: 0,
  14: 0},
 'tasks_available': {0: 3,
  1: 3,
  2: 3,
  3: 3,
  4: 3,
  5: 3,
  6: 3,
  7: 3,
  8: 3,
  9: 3,
  10: 3,
  11: 3,
  12: 3,
  13: 3,
  14: 3}}
pd.DataFrame(tasks_new)
```

Comment: You should include the expected output (*I want to have ...*) in form of a table, not just wording.

Comment: I have included it in the edit, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
idx_cols = ['distinct_id', 'first_name', 'activity']
tasks.set_index(idx_cols).unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()

    distinct_id first_name activity  tasks_completed  tasks_available
0             1        Joe    Climb                0                0
1             1        Joe     Jump                3                3
2             1        Joe      Run                0                0
3             2      Barry    Climb                0                0
4             2      Barry     Jump                3                3
5             2      Barry      Run                0                0
6             3      David    Climb                0                0
7             3      David     Jump                0                0
8             3      David      Run                3                3
9             4     Marcus    Climb                0                0
10            4     Marcus     Jump                0                0
11            4     Marcus      Run                3                3
12            5    Anthony    Climb                1                3
13            5    Anthony     Jump                0                0
14            5    Anthony      Run                0                0
```